# Implement a faster algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have been stuck on this question for days. Apparently I need to write a better algorithm to win the algorithm below. The below code is implemented from the famous Aima file. Is there any expert here who could guide me on how to win the algorithm?

```
(defun find-closest (list)
    (x (car (array-dimensions list)))
        (y (cadr (array-dimensions list)))
            (let ((elems (aref list x y)))
                (dolist (e elems)
                    (when (eq (type-of e) type)
                        (return-from find-closest (list x y)))) nil))
```

I tried implementing a DFS but failed and I do not quite know why. Below is my code.

```
 (defun find-closest (list)
   (let ((open (list list)) 
    (closed (list))
    (steps 0)
    (expanded 0)
    (stored 0))
    (loop while open do
      (let ((x (pop open))) 
        (when (finished? x)
          (return (format nil "Found ~a in ~a steps.
Expanded ~a nodes, stored a maximum of ~a nodes." x steps expanded stored)))
        (incf steps)
        (pushnew x closed :test #'equal)
        (let ((successors (successors x)))
          (incf expanded (length successors))
          (setq successors
            (delete-if (lambda (a)
                 (or (find a open :test #'equal)
                     (find a closed :test #'equal)))
                   successors))
          (setq open (append open successors))
          (setq stored (max stored (length open))))))))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better post in [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: What's Code Review SE. Sorry i am still quite new

Comment: @Sylwester this would be off-topic on Code Review as the code appears to not be working correctly, as in the author is looking for some fhelp in making the code work. See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Hero1134 Code Review Stack Exchange is a sister-site to Stack Overflow, where instead of asking for help solving specific programming problems (as you do on Stack Overflow), you instead take all the __working__ code you would like reviewed, and the answers will critique your code and suggest improvements in performance, readability, maintainability, etc. Do take a minute to look at the [Tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) if you are interested.

Comment: You should describe the problem a bit more. I assume this has to do with the book "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach", but since I don't have a copy, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Since the code isn't runnable and you didn't explain what problem you have with it or what the expected input and output are, it's pretty much impossible to say anything about it.

Comment: Thanks, all. I see... wow, I will use that in the future. Anyway, I am supposed to write an agent that is able to clean all dust faster than the dumb-traversal-vacuum-agent-with-radar.

Comment: @Phrancis Sorry. I though the question was about enhancement on working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code, the function `find-some-in-grid` returns the first found thing of `type`. This will, essentially, give you O(n * m) time for an n * m world (imagine a world, where you have one dirt on each line, alternating between "left-most" and "right-most".

Since you can pull out a list of all dirt locations, you can build a shortest traversal, or at least a shorter-than-dump traversal, by instead of picking whatever dirt you happen to find first you pick the closest (for some distance metric, from the code it looks like you have Manhattan distances (that is, you can only move along the X xor the Y axis, not both at the same time). That should give you a robot that is at least as good as the dumb-traversal robot and frequently better, even if it's not optimal.

With the provision that I do NOT have the book and base implementation purely on what's in your question, something like this might work:

```
(defun find-closest-in-grid (radar type pos-x pos-y)
  (labels ((distance (x y) 
              (+ (abs (- x pos-x)) 
                 (abs (- y pos-y)))))
     (destructuring-bind (width height) 
         (array-dimensions radar)
       (let ((best nil)
            ((best-distance (+ width height))))
         (loop for x from 0 below width
           do (loop for y from 0 below height
                 do (loop for element in (aref radar x y)
                       do (when (eql (type-of element) type)
                             (when (<= (distance x y) best-distance)
                                (setf best (list x y))
                                (setf best-distance (distance x y))))))))
         best)))
```

Comment: @Hero1134 To start with, `radar` is an array. You stuff that array in a list called open. While there's at least one element in the list, you pop it. Then you stuff non-arrays back in. All you need your "find next" function to do is to find the closest and what you've written seems to attempt to accomplish this in the least convenient way possible.

Comment: I shall try again. Thanks. But your answer is brilliant

Comment: Is there a way i could use pos-x pos-y without declaring it as the parameter of the function? Like instead of (defun find-closest-in-grid (radar type pos-x pos-y), i declare it as (defun find-closest-in-grid (radar type)